# Data Remodelling and transformation mysql to hdfs and mongodb

Tags: mysql, data-modeling, data-migration, bigdata

We are facing an issue of data migration. We have two heavily loaded tables. We used to make a join and fetch aggregated data from both tables in real time. Since due to increase in size we want to migrate it in mongodb with remodelling having a flat db layout to overcome joins. I researched a lot but i am not able to figure it out the exact tool or framework. Sqoop and flume migrate table from one system to another directly but not remodelling. I am not able to figure it out whether Spring XD or apache nifi transform as per my need.

**Pseudo steps are as follows**

step 1 (fetch from first system)

1) var a = select id, name, age from info where age > 10;

step 2 (fetch from first system)

2) var b = select address, income from professional_detail where id = a.id;

step 3 (insert in second system)

3) insert into aggregate_table (id, age, name, income, address) values (a.id, a,age,a.name, b.income, b.address)

Which is the exact framework or tool best suited in this? We only want to do sql query, bash command and java code. No other languages

Comment: You can do this with ETL tools . Please try with some available ETL tools like Talend. https://www.talend.com/download/talend-open-studio

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka pentaho Does kettle jobs fulfill the criteria ?

Comment: Yes sure You can use pentaho kettle jobs . its another ETL tool.

Comment: When you are finished, let us know how much faster (or slower) it is due to the "flat db layout to overcome joins".  (To be fair, please include the schema showing the indexes and the select(s).)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the questions and comments it is safe to say you need an ETL solution.

As you mention some tools, you seem to be looking at the Hadoop ecosystem, in this space Spark seems to be the most natural fit with your requirements.